# How can I load query from SQLite database into tableview in ios 7 ( xcode 5.1.1 )?

Tags: ios, sql, database, xcode, sqlite

I have an SQLite database named "BookDataBase.sqlite" with two columns : Category , Name .

It contains categories for books and some book names for each category .

I have a table view controller connected to class "CategoryTableViewController" which is a subclass of "UITableViewController" .

I want the table view to display the result for a query from the database where only the categories are displayed .

I have tried this code but it didn't work for me .

CategoryTableViewController.m  :

```
#import "CategoryTableViewController.h"
#import <sqlite3.h>

@interface CategoryTableViewController ()

@end

sqlite3 *BookDatabase;
NSString *databasepath;
const char *filepath;
NSString *querySQL;
const char *query_stmt;
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
NSMutableDictionary *BookRecord;
NSUserDefaults *BookData;
NSMutableArray *BookArray;


@implementation CategoryTableViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    databasepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"BookDatabase" ofType:@"sqlite"];
    filepath = [databasepath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(filepath, &BookDatabase) == SQLITE_OK) {


        querySQL = @"SELECT Category FROM BookTable Group By Categoy" ;
        query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(BookDatabase, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

                BookRecord =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:sqlite3_column_count(statement)];

                for (int i=0; i<sqlite3_column_count(statement); i++) {

                    NSString *ColName = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:sqlite3_column_name(statement, i)];
                    NSString *ColVal = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_value(statement, i)];




                    [BookRecord setObject:ColVal forKey:ColName];
                }


                [BookArray addObject:BookRecord];



            }


             sqlite3_finalize(statement);

        }

        sqlite3_close(BookDatabase);





    }





}




- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [BookArray count];
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CategoryTableViewCell";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];





    // Configure the cell...

    int row = [indexPath row];



    cell.textLabel.text = [BookArray[row] objectForKey:@"Category"];




    return cell;
}

@end
```

I have already added the libsqlite3 framework.

The database file is located in the app folder :

https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/Screen%20Shot%202014-08-15%20at%207.18.22%20PM.png?_subject_uid=104745578&w=AADDzW343bbSsnQ9wko1dFQ3yQes8N5tY9hJmEDb3qnwNw

The type for the table view prototype cell is set to basic and the cell identifier is "CategoryTableViewCell".

The name of the table in the database is "BookTable".

Can someone please help me fix this?

Feel free to rewrite my entire code if needed < but please keep in mind that it's a subcalass of "UITableViewController".

Thanks .

Comment: You wrote "it didn't work" - how exactly it does not work? Does it reads the data from the DB or do you have an error message?

Comment: @AlexAtNet The tableview is empty with nothing in it.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint on `[BookRecord setObject:ColVal forKey:ColName];` and check that the data is really added to the tableview?

Comment: So, what have you done to debug this?  Do you even know if the DB is being successfully read?  Do you even know if the DB file exists?

Comment: @AlexAtNet I put a breakpoint, and nothing turned up .

Comment: @HotLicks when I NSLog in the if statement of (sqlite3_open()) , it shows that the database file is found . And I also added the database manually to the app folder : http://www.mhdsamad.3eeweb.com/1.png/   . Do you think I didn't succeed in defining the database file path ?

Comment: @HotLicks Here is an updated link for the image https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/Screen%20Shot%202014-08-15%20at%207.18.22%20PM.png?_subject_uid=104745578&w=AADDzW343bbSsnQ9wko1dFQ3yQes8N5tY9hJmEDb3qnwNw

Comment: Don't post screen shots.  Even if the links are good (which those aren't).

Comment: I'll observe that if the open fails you silently bypass the entire DB access sequence.  And you have no NSLogs in there.  There's no evidence that you ever access any data.

Comment: @HotLicks OK, given the location of the database file and what I requested in my question, can you tell me of a way to do this from the start? If it 's not bothersome for you of course.

Comment: Step 1:  Learn how to *debug*.  (And note that a DB file in the bundle will be read-only.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FINALLY FOUND IT

Turns out I didn't add the database file to the main bundle .

I didn't know I should do that .